# Is my answer correct? I came up with this by following an example.

Tags: induction

Describe the set of strings that belong to the set A defined recursively as follows
BASIC STEP: λ ∈ A, 1 ∈ A
RECURSIVE STEP: If x ∈ A then 0x ∈ A and x0 ∈ A.

A is the set of all strings over alphabet {0, 1} that are consituted by a sequence of zeros followed by a sequence of ones  or a sequence of ones by a sequence of zeros and where both sequences have the same number of elements.

Comment: What is $\gamma$.  And you so a sequence of $1$s after or before a sequence of $0$ are possible.  How?  You start with $1$ but I don't any step that allows any string with two $1$s.  I just see you can have a single $\gamma$ or  single $1$ followed and/or preceeded by any number of $0$s.

Comment: " and where both sequences have the same number of elements"  Why?  You have 1 with zero 0s.  Those aren't equal. You have 01 so you also hav 001 and 0001 so you have 00010 and 000100 which... you don't describe at all.

Comment: Then my answer should be the sets {1,0},{0,1} and {0}? @fleablood

Comment: No.  Just think it out.  Draw pictures.  Read Dan Brumleve's analogy of parked cars.  You can have ... nothing... you can have "1" and whatever you have you can stick a 0 after it or you you can stick a 0 before it.  Not sure how to give hints on insights but.. what can you get by recursively sticking 0s before or after a $1$ or ""?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few things wrong with your interpretation.  Here's an analogy as a hint: the language is a parking lot and the elements are its states.  It starts out empty, so that's a possible state.  There is one guy who sometimes parks his red car there, but only if the lot is empty.  Everyone else who shows up has a blue car and they park it at one of the ends of the row of other cars, or anywhere if the lot is empty.

Comment: Is $\gamma$ an empty parking lot?

Comment: I was guessing $\lambda$ is the empty string since the language is binary.   Usually I see $\varepsilon$ for that.

Comment: yes  λ is an empty set.

Comment: Hmm.... not sure how when I typed l-a-m-b-d-a on my keypad it came out as g-a-m-m-a on the comments.  One of those eternal mysteries, I guess.